# Best practice Throwing error if find nil class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best practice when my query returns `nil`.

```
@resume = Resume.where(id: params[:id], interaction_id: params[:interaction_id]).first
@resume.update(resume_url: params[:resume_url])
```

If my query return nil it will throw `undefined method 'update' for nil:NilClass` error.

Should I use `if else` statement to check it `@resume` before the update, or use `begin rescue` to catch the errors?

Or have any other way to make the code better.

Comment: It heavily depends on what behaviour do you expect from your app when there are no records to update. Silently ignore?—`if`. Notify the user?—Do not `rescue` here, rescue in the global application handler and show a meaningful error message. Or use `rescue_with` rails helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@resume = Resume.where(id: params[:id], interaction_id: params[:interaction_id]).first
if @resume
  @resume.update(resume_url: params[:resume_url])
else
  flash[:error] = "Resume not found with id #{params[:id]}"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Blindly calling `first` on the dataset returned is a code smell in general.

There are two proper approaches to the problem:

If you expect any number of records returned:

```
(@resumes = Resume.where(...)).each do |resume|
  resume.update(resume_url: params[:resume_url])
end
```

If you are certain you should receive either one or none records:

```
@resumes = Resume.where(...)
case @resumes.size
when 0 then # flash or something reporting
when 1 
  (@resume = @resumes.first).update(resume_url: params[:resume_url])
else # flash or something reporting
end
```

Comment: The first example is useless, each with assigment. What the point of first example? How it is working?

Comment: Obviously is assignes the returned result, then iterates it and updates found records.

Comment: so, assigment result here is `true` ? What the point of this array full of `true`, sorry, I can't get the point.

Comment: Assignment’s RHO is what `where` returned.